# OrderBy tag in web config

Tags: c#, sql, web-config, config

I am trying to write a tag for an export in excel in web config. Until now I have the code like this:

```
<tableName>tbl_ODW_ParentCompany</tableName>
    <displayName>Parent Company</displayName>
    <export canExport="true" source="select name Name from tbl_ODW_ParentCompany "  sourceType="sql"></export>
    <listSources>
        <default>
            <listSource name="DefaultList" viewName="tbl_ODW_ParentCompany" orderBy="name"/>
        </default>
```

But none of those orderBy's work. What I expect is that the names in the export are ordered alphabetically.

The query :

```
SELECT dbo.tbl_ODW_ParentCompany.id, dbo.tbl_ODW_ParentCompany.name
FROM dbo.tbl_ODW_UserParentCompany
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_ODW_ParentCompany
    ON dbo.tbl_ODW_UserParentCompany.parentCompanyId =  dbo.tbl_ODW_ParentCompany.id
WHERE userID = userId order by dbo.tbl_ODW_ParentCompany.name
```

I tried to add asc in the `order by` clause but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort direct in query.

```
SELECT tbl.name as Name 
FROM tbl_ODW_ParentCompany tbl 
ORDER BY tbl.name;
```

Comment: I know that, I'll edit my post and I'll put the query,because it's more complicated than this